# Meteor 1.2 : Sharing Meteor.users between 2 applications over DDP

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, ddp

Let's say I have two web-applications completely different. `A` being my main application and `B`, an other forked app pretty heavy already. I want to share my `Meteor.users` collection between both of them so people can (auto)Login and navigate between both applications without any frictions, wether they are on the main app or the other.

So far, I tried going the DDP way with:

```
Meteor.connection = DDP.connect('http://localhost:3008/')

Accounts.connection = Meteor.connection

Meteor.users = new Meteor.Collection('users', {connection: Meteor.connection})

Meteor.connection.subscribe('users', function() {
    var users = Meteor.users.find()
    console.log(users.count())
})
```

With Meteor's magic, I can now login with my `A` account on `B`, it also seems I can update my docs through `B` via the web-console. Everything seems awesome. My problem is `B` being a real app too, I have some server-side logic going on there and it appears my users collection, `Meteor.user()` and so on are `undefined`. I need those users to be accessible from the server too and modify the collection.

Am I right to use DDP or should I look into solutions like `arunoda:meteor-cluster` or any other? Is it due to some changes made with 1.2 release?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `DDP.connect` on the server to access the users from the other server.